# Office365 Exchange – How do I add storage accounts? (DropBox, Google Drive, etc)

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, google-drive

Background: I am evaluating migration to office365 for a small company. Currently, they have and want to continue to use Google Drive for their document storage, so moving that part for OneDrive is a non-started currently.

The goal: enable google drive access through office365 exchange owa for end users.

In consumer versions of mail online (outlook.com), you can add storage providers like Google Drive and Dropbox.

[image]

In my current evaluation of office365 (Enterprise E3 seems to be what they give you when you sign up), I have found this preference:

[image]

But I cannot find the option anywhere to actually add an account. In owa, there is this screen:

[image]

But I cannot actually add an account. I cannot find a preference/option in the online office apps either.

I feel like this is either impossible to do or I am missing a setting. I have been searching google and online docs over the past few days and there is scant information that is not significantly old.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? That option in the consumer version of Outlook.com is for attaching files from other storage providers to emails you send from your Outlook.com account. Is it that you want users to be able to attach files from their Google Drive account to their emails in Office 365?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.I will clarify a bit in my opening

Comment: Sounds like this is what you are looking for: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6165960?hl=en this is assuming you’ll be using Outlook and not OWA, which is the norm with Office 365 users. There is a different culture with Office 365 than with google apps. Outlook is a true Office collaboration tool that integrates with the entire Office 365 suite of technology like Skype, teams, sharepoint, etc. So if your users have been using gmail for basic email/calendaring and expect to use another “web” product, they’ll need to change their thinking on what the purpose of Office 365 and Outlook is for

Comment: That is, unfortunately, for the installed versions. They will be using owa and smartphone access 100% of the time - and the online consumer version does support dropbox, drive, etc. I mean, it just makes it potentially not the product to use, but it seems to have the capabilities to do it based on the screens I linked, so just making sure I am not missing something obvious before I move on.